# Can CsvHelper map headers to two different class instances?

Tags: csvhelper

We are considering switching from LinqToCsv which is quite old to CsvHelper.  One instance that we would need to account for is that we have a CSV file with columns that need to get mapped to two different classes.

```
URL, MerchantId, ISBN, InternalCode
"https://blahblah.com", 1, 9781234567890, 1234
```

`URL` and `MerchantId` need to map to an instance of `MerchantProductRelBO` but `ISBN` and `InternalCode` need to map to an instance of `ProductBO`.

Can this be done by creating a custom mapping or would I need to resort to Reading the file by hand as described in https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file?

Answer (score 1):

If you add them both to another class, then there is no need to read by hand.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public MerchantProductRelBO MerchantProduct { get; set; }
    public ProductBO ProductBO { get; set; }
}

using (var reader = new StringReader("URL,MerchantId,ISBN,InternalCode\nhttps://blahblah.com,1,9781234567890,1234"))
using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
}
```

Otherwise, I believe you would need to read by hand.

```cs
using (var reader = new StringReader("URL,MerchantId,ISBN,InternalCode\nhttps://blahblah.com,1,9781234567890,1234"))
using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var merchantProducts = new List<MerchantProductRelBO>();
    var productBOs = new List<ProductBO>();

    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();

    while (csv.Read())
    {
        merchantProducts.Add(csv.GetRecord<MerchantProductRelBO>());
        productBOs.Add(csv.GetRecord<ProductBO>());
    }
}
```